# Is it possible to retrieve SharePoint Lists by CAML request

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-clientobject

Could anybody help me to retrieve SharePoint **Lists** (NOT List Items) by CAML request using Client Side Object Model (CSOM).

I know how to get List Items using CAML query (I can use GetItems() method in a List object):

```
public ListItemCollection GetItems(CamlQuery query_);
```

I would like to do the same thing with Lists, but can't find a way, is it possible?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
SP.Web.GetLists(CamlQuery query)
```

Comment: Why the downvote, folks? If you're going to downvote the question then at the very least you owe a comment to the OP explaining why.

Answer (score -1):

// "ctx" is the object of client context

```
ListCollection lists = web.Lists;                
ctx.Load(lists);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

In object "list" you will get all list names.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not an answer for my question :(